# Populating ActiveX comboboxes with distinct values

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, excel-tables

My issue is that I want to populate an **ActiveX control combobox** with a specific name, `List_Funds` as I renamed it. The population is based on a specific column in a table I have generated in my workbook called `Table_Funds`. I want the combobox to only populate the unique values of the table. The code should run when I open the workbook.

Code below with my current attempt:

Below the code is in a designated module containing all my declarations

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

' This module contains all constants and variable declarations
' **** Declarations ****

' Worksheets and workbooks
Public ws             As Worksheet
Public ws_O           As Worksheet
Public ws_S           As Worksheet
Public wkb            As Workbook

' Integers
Public i              As Integer
Public j              As Integer

' Variants, objects and ranges
Public Data           As Variant
Public Funds_List     As Object
Public rng            As Range
Public tbl            As ListObject

Sub Fixed()

    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws_O = wkb.Sheets("Overview")
    Set ws_S = wkb.Sheets("SQL")
    Set Funds_List = ws_O.OLEObjects("List_Funds").Object
    Set tbl = ws_O.ListObjects("Table_Funds")

End Sub
```

Below the code is in ThisWorkbook module

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
' Computing when opening workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Call modCnt.Fixed

    ' Populating table
    Data = modGlobal.GetSql(modGlobal.Compose_sSql(1))
    tbl.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    For i = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
        For j = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
            tbl.DataBodyRange(1 + i, 1 + j) = Data(j, i)
        Next j
    Next i

    ' Populating combobox
    With Funds_List
        For Each rng In tbl.ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange
            If Not .exists(rng.Value) Then ' < ---- code fails here
                .AddItem rng.Value
            End If
        Next rng
    End With


    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

My code fails at the line `If Not .exists(rng.Value) Then`
giving me

> run-time error 438 'Object does not support this property or method.'

The table is populating as it should (i.e. you can *disregard the section populating the table* as it calls on a sub in a different module) and watching the code I know that the `rng` takes on the correct value (first value in the databodyrange of my table).

Comment: `exists` is not a VBA command.  What are you trying to test?

Comment: @DarrellH I copied that code from another forum posts. I want to test whether the value in `rng` is already in my combobox and if it is not it should be added. This is to avoid duplicates that exists in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that someone created a function.  Try replacing this block:

```
' Populating combobox
Dim Exists As Boolean
Dim t As Long

Exists = False

With Funds_List
    For Each Rng In tbl.ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange
        For t = 1 To .ListCount - 1
            If Rng.Value = CStr(.List(t)) Then
                Exists = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next t
        If Exists = False Then
            .AddItem Rng.Value
        End If
    Next Rng
End With
```

Comment: This code stops running when it hits the duplicate. It should continue down the list and ignore the duplicates. I solved it by placing the line `Exists = False` below the start of the `For Each` loop. Also added a `.Clear` to allow for changes in the original table source.

Comment: It was supposed to stop running.  When it finds the duplicate, no more action required.  Only if there is no duplicate, then add the item.

Comment: The list is supposed to be populated with the unique value in the table, not until it hits the first duplicate. Either way I fixed my own version.